# What is going with visibility of protected overridden method in F#?

Tags: c#, f#

I have different result for reflection depending on the language: C# vs F#

C#

```
public abstract class TestHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    public abstract Task<HttpResponseMessage> MockableSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

var methods = typeof(TestHandler).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

`methods` contains `SendAsync`, `Dispose`, `MemberwiseClone`, and `Finalize`.

Now F#

```
open System.Net.Http
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks
open System.Reflection

[<AbstractClass>]
type TestHandler() = 
    inherit HttpMessageHandler()
    abstract member MockableSendAsync: HttpRequestMessage * CancellationToken -> Task<HttpResponseMessage>
    override this.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken) = this.MockableSendAsync(request, cancellationToken)

let methods = typeof<TestHandler>.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance)
```

`methods` contains only three methods, `SendAsync` is absent.

However, if I use `Public` binding flag, `methods` contains more entries including `SendAsync`:

```
let methods = typeof<TestHandler>.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public)
```

---

However, there is a difference in `RuntimeMethodInfo` of C# and F# versions.

For C# `Attributes` property is:
- PrivateScope, **Family**, Virtual, HideBySig,

whereas for F# it is:
- PrivateScope, **Public**, Virtual, HideBySig

WTF?! Where is promised respect for `protected` visibility modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that they never did promise respect for the visibility modifier.

In the F# 4.1 Spec, section 10.5:

> #### Accessibility Annotations
>
> The table lists the accessibilities that can appear in user code:
>
> **public**
>
> No restrictions on access.
>
> **private**
>
> Access is permitted only from the enclosing type, module, or namespace
>   declaration group.
>
> **internal**
>
> Access is permitted only from within the enclosing assembly, or from assemblies whose name is listed using the
>   InternalsVisibleTo attribute in the current assembly.
>
> ...
>
> The CLI compiled form of all non-public entities is *internal*.
>
> **Note:** The family and protected specifications are not supported in this version of the F# language.

What reflection is showing you is unfortunately, expected behavior.

Comment: That's a pity. My expectation was that they support following protected when overriding, but do not allow to introduce new 'protected' methods.

Comment: @PavelVoronin If this behavior is deal breaking for you, you could have a post-build rewrite with Mono.Cecil changing method visibility.